# How to create multiple form update(edit) view in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I need to create function based or class based view which can edit/update multiple forms in one page. How to create this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have more than one form appear on a template by passing two different form variables in the view. Something like this:

```
def formview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
        form1 = form.Form1()
        form2 = form.Form2()

    context = {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2}
```

Then in your template you simply need to handle each form within the form tags like so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form1.as_p }}
    {{ form2.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: this is for creation i need for (change/edit/update). I tried it but it didn’t work ---- `def home_edit(request):
    clients = Clients.objects.all()
    a_obj = AboutMe.objects.last()
    s_obj = Services.objects.last()
    p_obj = Pricing.objects.last()
    f_obj = Facts.objects.last()
    c_obj = Clients.objects.last()

    a_form = AboutMeCreateForm(instance=a_obj)
    s_form = ServicesCreateForm(instance=s_obj)
    p_form = PricingCreateForm(instance=p_obj)
    f_form = FactsCreateForm(instance=f_obj)`

Comment: Can you add your models.py, forms.py and views.py?